# Left join effectiveness when using IS NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I'm using a left join to check if certain types of information have been stored in the database.

I'm wondering if a lot of resources will be wasted if the joined table contains a lot of rows which matches the JOIN clause.

i.e.:

```
SELECT Applications.*
FROM Applications
LEFT JOIN SomeFeatureRows ON (SomeFeatureRows.ApplicationId = Applications.Id)
WHERE SomeFeatureRows.Id IS NULL;
```

Do the DB scan through all rows in `SomeFeatureRows` to see if there is a row where `Id` is `NULL`?

I just want to check if there is a row or not in that table (with the specified application id).

**Edit, might as well include the real SQL statement:**

```
SELECT organizations.id AS OrganizationId, 
       organizations.Name, 
       Application.Id as ApplicationId,
       Application.Name as ApplicationName,
       Account.id       AS AccountId, 
       Account.Email, 
       Account.Username ,
       SentEmails. SentAtUtc 
FROM   organizations 
       INNER JOIN applications ON ( organizations.id = applications.organizationid ) 
       LEFT JOIN Incidents ON ( organizations.id = Incidents.organizationid ) 
       LEFT JOIN SentEmails ON ( organizations.id = SentEmails.organizationid AND EmailTypeName = 'IncidentsReminder') 
       CROSS apply (SELECT accounts.id, 
                           accounts.email, 
                           accounts.username 
                    FROM   accounts, 
                           organizationmembers 
                    WHERE  accounts.id = organizationmembers.accountid 
                           AND organizationmembers.organizationid = 
                               organizations.id) 
       Account 
WHERE  Incidents.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) is a very good article explaining the different techniques and performance benefits of using: `Not Exists` vs. `Not In` vs. `Left join / Is null`

To summarize:
`LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` is less efficient, since it makes no attempt to skip the already matched values in the right table, returning all results and filtering them out instead. Use `Not Exists` for best performance as it will create a [LEFT ANTI SEMI JOIN](http://sqlity.net/en/1360/a-join-a-day-the-left-anti-semi-join/) in the execution plan.

Comment: Don't forget you can check the execution plan to see what happens.